# How do I return the first non-repeated letter, regardless of the case?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I am trying to make a program that counts the occurrences of a letter in a string, but I don't know how to make it case insensitive while preserving the original letter.

I tried assigning each item to a dictionary with the key being the number of occurrences in the string but, if I say for example, `abA`  it will count `A` and `a` as different letters.

```
import operator

def first_non_repeating_letter(string):
    string = string.lower()
    di = {}
    for i in string:
       di[i] = string.count(i)
    if all(value > 1 for value in di.values()):
       return ""
    else:
       var =  min(di.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1))[0]
       return var
```

Output:
Instead of

```
output = {"a":1 , b:"1" , "A":1}
```

I want:

```
output = {"A/a" : 2, "b":1}
```

and returning: `the repeated letter is A or a`

Comment: why overcomlicating and not use `Counter` on lowercased string?

Comment: because if i do that then i will not be able to return the original letter

Comment: use copy of the string and post your expected result

Comment: Save the string as temp_string = string.lower() so you can still return the original string

Comment: i want to return the original letter not the string

Comment: You said that you are ```trying to make a program that counts the occurrences of a letter in a string``` but now you say that you want to return a letter. Which is it?

Comment: i made a mistake and i tried to edit it but i couldnt because someone already edited it

Comment: @Raymoun17 what are you trying to use this for?

Comment: for example if  u type in the string "sTress" it will output the letter "T" as the first non repeated letter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will merge all lower/upper case characters and their count to one dictionary:

```
from collections import Counter
from itertools import groupby

s = 'AbCxbaBc'

out = {}
for v, g in groupby(sorted(Counter(s).items(), key=lambda k: 2*ord(k[0].upper()) - k[0].islower()), lambda k: k[0].lower()):
    l = [*g]
    out[''.join(i[0] for i in l)] = sum(i[1] for i in l)

print(out)

# non repeated letters:

non_repeating = [k for k, v in out.items() if v==1]
print('Non repeated letters:', non_repeating)

# first non repeated letter:

if non_repeating:
    m = min(map(lambda i: (s.index(i), i), non_repeating))
    print('First non repeated letter:', m[-1])
else:
    print('All letters are repeating!')
```

Prints:

```
{'aA': 2, 'bB': 3, 'cC': 2, 'x': 1}
Non repeated letters: ['x']
First non repeated letter: x
```

Comment: thats closer to what i want but the problem isnt in counting the letter its in returning the non repeated letter with the original case

Comment: @Raymoun17 so return all keys from dictionary `out` where the value is `1`

Comment: but that would also return the repeated letters ex: "sTresS" would return in this case : "T" and "S" but the letter "S" is already repeated in the form of "s"

Comment: oh didnt notice

Comment: @Raymoun17 No, in this case it will print `['e', 'r', 'T']` as non-repeated letters

Comment: then how do i only return the first one ? should i make a new list out of the previous output  ?

Comment: Thank you very much it worked but what if the string doesnt contain any repeated letter how do i return none or "no unique letter" ?

Comment: @Raymoun17 Now in my code I just print `print('All letters are repeating!')`, so in your code you should probably return or set some variable, maybe raise Exception. depends on your case.

Answer (score 2):

This should work for what you need it to.

```
import operator

def first_non_repeating_letter(string):
    dict = {}
    lowercase_string = string.lower()
    # first we have to make a dictionary counting how many occurrences there are
    for ch in lowercase_string:
        if ch in dict:
            dict[ch] = dict[ch] + 1
        else:
            dict[ch] = 1

    # check if the number of occurrences is one, then return it
    for ch in lowercase_string:
        if ch in dict and dict[ch] == 1:
            index = lowercase_string.find(ch)
            return string[index]
```

Example:

Input: "sTreSs"

Output: "T"

Comment: will it return it with the original case

Comment: but this returns the repeated letter i want the non repeated letter

Answer (score 1):

This may help

```
import collections
c = collections.Counter('PaRrOt'.lower())
sorted(c.items(), key=lambda c: c[0])
[('a', 1), ('o', 1), ('p', 1), ('r', 2), ('t', 1)]
```

Source
https://stackoverflow.com/a/22819467/5202279

EDIT: Based on OP's comments.

You can simply check if the dictionary value for that particular alphabet is 1 then it is non-repeating.

As for particular_case of alphabet. see if the alphabet is non repeating than match it with regex to original string.

Comment: but how do i return "R" as the first occurence of  the "r" letter ?

Comment: That is not what you asked in your question and why do you want first occurrence.

Comment: sorry,  i made a mistake, let me clarify :

Comment: if i have a string ex: "stress" i want the outpt to be "t" as the first non repeated letter in the string another edxample would be "streSs" whch the output would be "t" and another eample would be "aabA" which the output would be "b" and not "A"

Comment: so you want non repeating alphabets? do you also need their letter_case ?

Comment: Yes thats exactly what i want

Answer (score 1):

You could always create a pair of mappings: one of the case-folded characters to their counts, and one to their first occurrence.

```
from collections import Counter

some_string = 'Some string'
lower_string = some_string.casefold()
count = Counter(lower_string)
firsts = dict(zip(lower_string, some_string))
```

Now, for and character in `count`, you can look up its original appearance in `firsts`.